# Create Task Items With Custom List Dataview in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I created 2 custom lists in Sharepoint 2010:

List #1: INTERNAL PROCESSES (fields: Process Title, Reference)

List #2: PROCESS STEPS (fields: Step Title, Step Description, Process Title[lookup of 1 item in previous list], Department Assigned)

I created an action in the display form for list INTERNAL PROCESSES called "Create Instance"...when user clicks on it, redirects user to

mypage.aspx?processID={itemID}
(I couldn't find a way to pass the title instead of the ID in the querystring...)

Up to here is what I have done so far.
Now, I need to accomplish the following in mypage.aspx

1) lookup in INTERNAL PROCESSES using processID received in queryString, if field Reference is not NULL, ask user to enter a value for Reference

(eg. if Reference contains the word "Member", ask user to enter the Member Name)

2) get Process Title from list INTERNAL PROCESSES for processID received in querystring

3) For each list item in PROCESS STEPS where field Process Title matches Process Title looked up in step#2 , create a new TASK list item with the

following values:
a) TASK Title = Step Title + Value entered in step#1 (if any)
b) TASK Description = Step Description
c) TASK Assigned to = Department Assigned

I'd like to avoid using code, if at all possible because I've never done it, if code is required please point me in the right direction...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

hey you would not required to use code if you are good at designing SharePoint designer workflows what you would have to do is create custom action using desginer and you can invoke a wrkflow using custom action, which would create a task for you in task list for more details have a look at following article

http://manish-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/01/creating-custom-actions-using.html